# Which drupal distribution suitable for managing online courses

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

Id like to know which drupal distribution suitable for an online courses management site similar to http://www.campusmalaysia.com/ , any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many options (& distributions) though when it comes to building online courses management site. Which one you need is entirely dependent on your user requirements. I would recommend starting with taking a look at [the resources guide for Drupal for Educational Institutions](https://www.drupal.org/resource-guides/drupal-for-educational-institutions).